# Square root of an even polynomial is holomorphic

Tags: complex-analysis, functions, polynomials

Given an even degree polynomial $p(x)$, all of whose roots satisfy $|z| < R$.
Explain why there is a holomorphic (i.e. analytic) function $h(z)$ defined on the region $R < |z| < ∞$ which satisfies $h(z)^2 = p(z)$.

Answer (score 2):

The only obstruction to the existence of a holomorphic square root is whether $\text{Arg}h(z)$ is well-defined up to an integer multiple of $2\pi$ given $\text{Arg}p(z)$. We shall show that for $|z|>R$, $\text{Arg}p(z)$ can be defined up to an even multiple of $2\pi$. Then it follows that $\text{Arg}h(z)$ is defined up to an integer multiple of $2\pi$, and we are done.

The previous assertion can be proved by showing that, the smooth change in $\text{Arg}p(z)$ when $z$ traverses any contour $\gamma$ in the region $R<|z|<\infty$ is an even multiple of $2\pi$. If $\gamma$ encloses all the zeros of $p(z)$, then by Rouche's theorem, we have
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma d\log p(z)&=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_\gamma\frac{p'(z)}{p(z)}dz\\
&=\text{number of zeros}\\
&=\text{degree of }p(z)
\end{align*}
which is even. If $\gamma$ does not enclose the zeros, then by Rouche's again there is no change in $\text{Arg}$. This completes the proof.

Comment: @Mmm Please take a look of answer.