# A polynomial of even degree has a holomorphic square root on a neighbourhood of infinity

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, polynomials

> Given an even degree polynomial p(x)
> , all of whose roots satisfy |z|<R
> . Explain why there is a holomorphic (i.e. analytic) function h(z)
> defined on the region R<|z|<∞
> which satisfies $h(z)^2=p(z)$
> .

This question has been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290968/square-root-of-an-even-polynomial-is-holomorphic) but I don't really understand the solution. I'm hoping someone can help me figure out the details

Clearly we want something like $h=\exp(\frac{1}{2} \log p(z))$ so our task is to define $\log p(z)$.

Let our candidate for $\log p(z)$ be $f(z)= \int_{R}^z \frac{p'(w)}{p(w)} dw$ defined on $|z|>R$.

I am happy that $f(z)$ is path independent up to a multiple of $4\pi i$, and so $e^\frac{f}{2}$ is well defined (using argument principle).

I don't understand why $f$ is holomorphic or why $e^{f/2}=p(z)$. Please could someone explain to me why this is the case with as many details as possible.

Comment: it may be easier to use $w=1/z$ and notice that on $|w|<1/R$ one has $f(w)=p(1/z)$ analytic with any continuous choice of $\sqrt {w^{2n}} =\pm w^n$

Comment: @Conrad "with any continuous choice of w2n−−−√=±wn" what do you mean exactly?

Comment: it means that at the origin there are two square roots that are continuous and hence holomorphic, so you need to choose one

Comment: I dont understand why there is a holomorphic square root on an open ball around the origin. " that are continuous and hence holomorphic" or how this is true

Comment: let's take an example like $P(z)=(z-1)(z-2)$ then $f(w)=\frac{(1-w)(1-2w)}{w^2}$ and on the disc of radius $1/2$ clearly $\sqrt {(1-w)(1-2w)}$ exists as a power series while the denominator becomes $\sqrt w^2$ and for that we can choose either $w$ or $-w$ so $\sqrt f$ becomes a holomorphic function on the punctured disc of radius $1/2$, hence $\sqrt P$ is holomorphic on its exterior which is precisely the exterior of the disc of radius $2$; the same analysis applies to any even degree polynomial

Comment: the square root of a polynomial of even degree has branch singularities only at the roots of odd order (even such) so you can get a branch by connecting them in pairs (you can choose the division in pairs arbitrarily but of course you general get different branches for different choices) with disjoint Jordan arcs while infinity is a pole of order half the degree; for the square root of a polynomial of odd degree, infinity is always a branch singularity too in addition to the roots of odd order (now odd in number) and again you get a branch by connecting said roots and infinity in pairs by arcs